# Nowadays, which MVC frameworks (such as Ruby on Rails) are widely in use and also very cool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, frameworks

Seems like more companies are using Ruby on Rails nowadays.  What are some other frameworks that are commonly in use nowadays and some that make you go "wow, this is cool"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're a .NET dev the defacto MVC platform is Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC.

A lot of java people i know are using Grails for new projects.

Python's platform tends to be Django.

In the PHP world it's CakePHP or Symfony (although I'm not sure the later is actually MVC).